# Three-phase transformer with only two cores?

Tags: transformer, three-phase

I'm an electrician. My foreman said the transformer we're having installed is three-phase, but only has two cores. The cores are placed in separate compartments, with a divider between them. I've never heard of anything like this. The three phase transformers I've seen have three cores, placed relatively close, each core having a primary and secondary winding, wired either delta-wye, or delta-delta etc.

Does anyone know what this is? How can a transformer with only two sets of windings produce three-phase power? It's for a relatively small commercial building.

Comment: en.wikipedia on [open delta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power#Transformer_connections).

Comment: There's also the [Scott T transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott-T_transformer#Back_to_back_arrangement).